# how do i move all files from one folder to another in terminal

Tags: find

I have searched various forums with variations on the question -

I am trying to move all files including those in sub folders from one folder to another - just the files not the folders.

This command works for directories

```
find ~/Desktop/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos
```

but this command I tried for folders does not

```
find ~/Desktop/Folder1/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ~/Videos/Folder2
```

Comment: On the second `find` you told it to find FILES (-type f) so of course it's won't see folder - you told it not to.  I'm not sure what you are after, but `-type d` is a directory .. use `man find` to view the type options...

Comment: You seem to be making a distinction between "folders" and "directories". What do you mean? What is the 2nd command attempting to do? How does it fail? Are you trying to move only directoris and not their contents?

Comment: As @terdon noted, you should [edit] your question to clarify. In this type of question, it is good to provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find /path/to/photos -type f -exec mv -nv -t '/path/to/master' -- {} +
```

found the original question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880246/move-only-files-recursively-from-multiple-directories-into-one-directory-with-mv

Test code on my CentOS virtual machine:

```
mkdir -p dir
mkdir -p dir/subdir1
mkdir -p dir/subdir2
mkdir -p dir/subdir3
mkdir -p dir1
touch dir/subdir1/file11
touch dir/subdir1/file12
touch dir/subdir1/file13
touch dir/subdir1/file14
touch dir/subdir2/file21
touch dir/subdir2/file22
touch dir/subdir2/file23
touch dir/subdir3/file31
touch dir/subdir3/file32
touch dir/subdir3/file33
touch dir/file1
touch dir/file2
touch dir/file3
find dir/ -type f -exec mv -nv -t dir1/ -- {} +
```

Comment: mint@mint-HP-Pro3500-Series:~$ find /Desktop/Folder1 -type f -exec mv -nv -t '/Desktop/Folder2' -- {} +
find: ‘/Desktop/Folder1’: No such file or directory  I have also tried find /Home/Mint/Desktop/Folder1 etc - same result No such file

Comment: I've tested it on my CentOS Virtual Machine, It works fine. Maybe you can try the test code I appended to the answer.

Comment: make sure you enter the right path.  I create temp dirs and files to test it.

Comment: Many thanks for the help - do you mean type this line into terminal.......find dir/ -type f -exec mv -nv -t dir1/ -- {} +

Comment: Just make sure you have 'dir/' and 'dir1' in your current working dir.    'dir' is the source and 'dir1' is the target.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880246/move-only-files-recursively-from-multiple-directories-into-one-directory-with-mv    You can also read the original answer to get more details.

Comment: Sorry but I am making a complete hash of this - is there confusion on what I think is a Directory - Home Desktop Videos Pictures Documents Music and what I refer to as a Folder whch contains yet more folders and sub folders all containing files - folder created by right clicking Create New Folder - both my folders are on my desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99682/discussion-between-kevin-and-smokeyone).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```bash
$ ll dir1
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 rick rick 4096 Oct  8 21:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 60 rick rick 4096 Oct  8 21:30 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 rick rick 4096 Oct  8 21:20 dir2/
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick    6 Oct  8 21:19 filea

$ mkdir dir3

$ find dir1/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t dir3

$ ll dir3
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  2 rick rick 4096 Oct  8 21:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 61 rick rick 4096 Oct  8 21:31 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick    6 Oct  8 21:19 filea
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick    6 Oct  8 21:20 fileb
```

`fileb` used to be in `dir1/dir2` but is now merged into `dir3` along with files from `dir1`

To save typing you can put the command into a function in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
function adopt () {
    find "$1"/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t "$2"
}
```

After saving `~/.bashrc` reopen the terminal and you can now use:

```bash
cd ~
adopt Desktop/dir1 Videos/dir2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information but it would mean I would have to go through all the folders and sub folders to find their names -

Comment: @smokeyone No just specify the top folder name. The command goes through all the sub-folders and finds all the filenames automatically.

Comment: @smokeyone I've created a function that calls the command. This saves typing a long command in the terminal.

Comment: you can see I am making a hash of this ........  mint@mint-HP-Pro3500-Series:~$ mkdir -p dir
mint@mint-HP-Pro3500-Series:~$ mkdir -p desktop
mint@mint-HP-Pro3500-Series:~$